# In case of RdBu colormap, why cm.get_cmap is not giving dark red and blue color by (0,1)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am trying to get the list of the RdBu colormap color, but (0.0,1.0) is not giving the color dark Red and dark Blue, why? How can I get the first and last color as a dark red and blue?

I have tried numbers of different options, won't get the dark Red and blue in either one.

Colors = cm.get_cmap('RdBu',100)
print(Colors([0,1]))

or

cmap = cm.RdBu(np.linspace(0,1,200))

[[  4.03921569e-01   0.00000000e+00   1.21568627e-01   1.00000000e+00]
 [  4.06865689e-01   9.42118589e-04   1.22039687e-01   1.00000000e+00]]

which is not dark blue or red! :(

Comment: `print(Colors([0.0, 1.0]))` will give you the first and last color.

Comment: But the colors are not the same as the first and last color of the RdBu. I don't get it why!

Comment: They are; `[0.40392157 0.         0.12156863 1.        ]` and 
 `[0.01960784 0.18823529 0.38039216 1.        ]` respectively. Maybe you want to show a complete verifiable code in the question?